# SourceKitService crash with Bridging-Header and Parse

Tags: iphone, swift, parse-platform, ios8, xcode6-beta6

I realize that there are numerous questions regarding XCode 6 beta 6 and its crashing of SourceKitService, but so far none of these answers have quite applied to my problem. SourceKitService does indeed crash, but only when I include the Parse SDK into my Bridging-Header. When I remove `#include <Parse/Parse.h>` from the bridging header, syntax highlighting returns to normal and all is good, minus the resulting errors from Parse not being present. While I haven't seen any other threads with a problem like this, I'm curious as to whether anyone else is experiencing such a problem. From my understanding, Parse is a relatively widely-used framework and I can't imagine that nobody else is having this trouble.

Thanks for your help, as this is my first post on StackOverflow, I apologize in advance for any faux-pas I may have committed. ^_^

Edit: I might also add that when I include `#include <Parse/Parse.h>` in the bridging header, despite crashing SourceKitService, the program compiles correctly and works as intended.

Comment: How are you adding the Parse framework to your app?

Comment: I took Parse.framework, Bolts.framework, and ParseFacebookUtils.framework and dragged them into the navigator sidebar in XCode. They appear (along with all of the other dependency frameworks listed on the [Parse Quickstart Page](https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/ios/native/existing) under my Supporting Files group. Bolts, Parse, and ParseFacebookUtils all appear in the "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" tab in the general app settings. Parse is then bridged using `#include <Parse/Parse.h>` in the Projectname-Bridging-Header.h file.

Comment: Well Xcode beta 7 was released today. Why don't you try the newest version?

Comment: Downloading now! Posted this before they released.

Comment: Let me know of the results, please.

Comment: Problem fixed in Xcode6-beta7. Thanks for your attention.